# Json allows trailing comma

Tags: .net, json

I have trailing comma in my .json file in asp solution.

```
    { "key": "Value1", "text": "Add new value" },
    { "key": "Value2", "text": "value 2" },
    { "key": "Value3", "text": "value 3" }, 
]
```

I was very surprised when my teamlead told me "it won't work" while reviewing my code changes, because it works =) I have not known before about this detail and that this comma is prohibited in json. Our question is why does it work in  VS2017 solution? Probably compilator does anything with this comma.
I use this code to deserialize:

```
JsonFormat value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonFormat>(jsonText);
```

Comment: How do you _read_ this json string?

Comment: Maybe it accepts [json5](https://github.com/json5/json5)?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json has an issue for this: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/818

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Json allows trailing comma

Nope, no it doesn't. That isn't valid JSON. Some parsers will *allow it*, but then: some parsers will allow comments which are *also* invalid.

Trailing commas are not valid in JSON.

> Our question is why does it work in VS2017 solution?

Because some parsers will try to parse as much as they can, without enforcing strict conformity. Presumably this is one such case.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be true. I'm trying to find how JsonConvert works "inside" now.